# Declare a class variable with a function

Tags: python, string, function, class, selenium-webdriver

**My Code:**

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Business:
Job_Trade: str = None

def add_variable(class_name, variable_name, valuee):
setattr(class_name, variable_name, valuee) # Default Value is `None`
business = Business()

business.Job_Trade = 'Licensed Customer Service Representative'

add_variable(business, 'Company', 'Global Payments')

print(business.Company)
print(business.Job_Trade)
print(business)
```

**Result:**

```
Global Payments
Licensed Customer Service Representative
Business(Job_Trade='Licensed Customer Service Representative')
```

**Required:**
I Need This, When I Print.

```
print(business)
```

**Required Result**

```
Business(Job_Trade='Licensed Customer Service Representative', Company='Global Payments')
```

**Do not use it**

```
Company: str = None
```

Do not use it as a manual declaration variable of 'class Business:'. This way I have to insert a lot of entries in different parts of the code, and it causes error many times.

***I need a function to declare it.***

Please help to solve the puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding this function to your class:

```
    def __str__(self):
        f = []
        for name,value in vars(self).items():
            f.append("{}='{}'".format(name,value))
        return "{}({})".format( __class__.__name__,",".join(f))
```

It should achieve your required result:

```
print(business)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need a dataclass and there's no reason (that I can discern) why you want to treat Job_Trade as a special case.

I suggest:

```
class Business():
    def __init__(self):
        ...
    def __str__(self):
        r = []
        for k, v in self.__dict__.items():
            r.append(f'{k}=\'{v}\'')
        return self.__class__.__name__ + '(' + ', '.join(r) + ')'

business = Business()
business.Job_Trade = 'Licensed Customer Service Representative'
business.Company = 'Global Payments'

print(business)
```

**Output:**

```
Business(Job_Trade='Licensed Customer Service Representative', Company='Global Payments')
```